# How to use dependency injection for inherited class?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, ninject, asp.net-web-api

Here I use DI framework (Ninject) and it works fine. But One of the problem facing is, I have a base class with a single constructor that takes an implementation of an interface.

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    readonly IAccessService _accessService; 
    public BaseApiController(IAccessService accessService)
    {
        this._accessService = accessService;
    }
}
```

When I inherit from this base class to all other controllers which have the constructors that takes implementation of the their own interfaces. I get error 'BaseApiController' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments,  Ok, I understood that. The derived class is

```
 public class DiscoverController  : BaseApiController
{
    readonly IDiscoverService _discoverService;
    readonly IAccessService _accessService;

    public DiscoverController(IDiscoverService discoverService,IAccessService accessService)  
    {
        _accessService = accessService;
        _discoverService = discoverService;
    }
}
```

How could I do this without modify the derived class ctor to take a similar parameter and pass that value on to the base ctor, I would appreciate it if you suggest better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying derived constructor to have it pass argument to base class:

```
public class DiscoverController  : BaseApiController
{
   readonly IDiscoverService _discoverService;
   readonly IAccessService _accessService;

   public DiscoverController(IDiscoverService discoverService,IAccessService accessService)  : base(accessService)
   {
      _discoverService = discoverService;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As @Christian said, the error is a C# compiler error, because you will have to pass the dependency through.

As you probably are already noticing, having such base class isn't a really pleasant way of working. You will have to inject this dependency into every controller and pass it on to the base controller. Even worse, when the base controller needs a second dependency, you will have to update all constructors of your controllers.

What you are doing wrong is that you:

- Use inheritance instead of composition and
- use a base class to apply cross-cutting concerns (which will be a violation of both the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) the moment you add a second cross-cutting concern to that base class).

You use this `IAccessService` in the base class probably to do certain security checks. Instead of using base classes, there are better methods. A general solution is to use decorators, but this doesn't work with Web API. Instead, with Web API you can use DelegateHandlers and add them to the pipeline. Such handler acts like a decorator and allows you to transparently apply cross-cutting concerns such as security.

Answer (score 1):

Modify DiscoverController using **: base** keyword (you will use parent constructor):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx