# .NET 6 DI for base class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

In .NET 6 appeared new feature is DI by type anonymous delegate:
[image]

Questing:
I have many clases inherited from based class with constructor.

now I have to write such long initializations
[image]

Isn't there a way to get rid of this writing?, for example, like this (psevdocode)

[image]

Comment: The imaged don't show `DI by anonymous delegate` and the question you asked has nothing to do with DI anyway.

Comment: Use a container class which contains all the service references. This way you only need to provide the base class with one object. Also if you need to add a service to the base class it only needs to be added in the container class, instead of all the subclasses constructors.

Comment: Can you share the code in the question and not the images. The code in the image has many errors. Did you try passing null to base constructor for the missing arguments?

Comment: I don't see the connection between the code at the beginning and the question about base classes. If the container can resolve the constructor arguments then it can resolve an instance of the class, whether it inherits from something or not.

Comment: okay. I just thought maybe something new was introduced about this in .net 6, which will help inject into the base class without passing through the child how it do in .MapGet()

Comment: Prevent posting [images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: The best way to get rid of this syntax is to [get rid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42886992/264697) of your base classes [all together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29601342/264697).

Answer (score 2):

This is how [parameter binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#parameter-binding) in [minimal APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0) (introduced in .NET 6) works and this is handled by the framework (ASP.NET Core). But it is not completely new idea and it is not bound to the anonymous labmdas - injection in controllers actions via [`FromServicesAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-1.1#action-injection-with-fromservices-1) is present from the first ASP.NET Core (see the [applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromservicesattribute?view=aspnetcore-1.0#applies-to) section) version.

As for tackling the parameter injection into the base class issue - one way around would be just creating class holding those parameters, register it in DI and injecting it. Something like this:

```cs
public class BaseClassParameters
{ 
    public BaseClassParameters (A a, B b, ...)  {A = a; ...}
    public A A { get; }
    ...
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(BaseClassParameters p) { // copy from p}
}


public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public ChildClass(BaseClassParameters p): base(p) // can create ChildClassParameters : BaseClassParameters  if needed or just add deps on this level
    {
    }
}


services.AddTransient<BaseClassParameters>(); // or use needed lifetime for class hierarchy here
```